# Outputting the product html price increased of 20%

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In WooCommerce, I am trying to output the product html price increased of 20% using this code:

```
echo $product->get_price_html(); // +20%
```

I have tried for a long time to get it working but unfortunately I cannot do so.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to know that the variable $product is an instance of WC_Product class, that will allow you to apply to it [any methods from this WC_Product class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html).

> You can use [**`WC_Product method get_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price) and [**`WC_Product method adjust_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_adjust_price) this way:

```
// Get the numerical (float) price value
$product_price = (float) $product->get_price();

// calculate 20% of product price
$add_to_price = $product_price * 0.2;

// Adjust the new displayed price
$product->adjust_price( $add_to_price );

// Displaying the new adjusted price html
echo $product->get_price_htm();
```

So now you finally get the html product price output increased of 20% simply reusing [WC_Product get_price_html() method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_price_html)…

Comment: Sorry to jump in here.  I would like to alter 'get_price_html()'  to  Output the sum of: Product Price + (Number of characters entered into the Custom Field * £2).  Would your code, above, also be the direction I would need to pursue to achieve such a goal, albeit with relevant modifications.  I have tried the code but it is causing the website to not load, so thought I would ask, before spending further time trying to modify the code for my own purposes.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Craig Since WooCommerce 3.0+ `get_price_html()` is deprecated now you need to use `wc_price()` instead or the filter hook `wc_price`. But if you are using WooCommerce 2.6.x the best way is using the dedicated filter hook `woocommerce_get_price_html`. There is a lot of related answer here in StackOverFlow.